# RecursiveFree Function - Warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, nodes, quadtree

I have a function which recursively frees:

```
#include "treeStructure.h"

void destroyTree (Node* p)
{
    if (p==NULL)
        return;
    Node* free_next = p -> child; //getting the address of the following item before p is freed
    free (p); //freeing p
    destroyTree(free_next); //calling clone of the function to recursively free the next item
}
```

**treeStructure.h:**

```
struct qnode {
  int level;
  double xy[2];
  struct qnode *child[4];
};
typedef struct qnode Node;
```

I keep getting the error

> Warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

and its pointing to 'p'.

I don't understand why this is occurring.

Can someone please explain and inform me how to fix this?

Comment: @usr I have linked a header file which has the Node struct. I've added that above to show how it's linked.

Comment: Child is an array of pointers to Nodes, not a single pointer to Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error message because a pointer to an array of `Node` (`child`) is not convertible to a pointer to `Node` (`p`).

As `child` is an array of four pointers to `Node` you have to free them seperately:

```
void destroyTree (Node* p)
{
    if (!p) return;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        destroyTree(p->child[i]);

    free(p);
}
```

Comment: @Swordfish the parameter would be Node** p, wouldn't it? The child field is of the type Node**

Comment: @anon2000 `child[i]` is of type `Node*`.